# Log-log scale smooth histogram

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms, logarithmic-scale

How can I create a smooth histogram with a log-log scale?

I can use `Histogram[data, "Log", "LogCount"]` to get a log-log histogram, or I can use `SmoothHistogram[data]` to get a smooth histogram, but is there a way to combine these two functionalities?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply get the [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution.html) and build the plot as you'd like:

```
data = Table[Sin[x]^3 + 1, {x, 0, 6 Pi, 0.1}];
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
LogLogPlot[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0.01, 2}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps an approximation like this may help

Some data from the help:

```
sizes = FileByteCount /@  FileNames["*.nb", 
        FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", 
        "System", "ReferencePages", "Symbols"}]];

Show[Histogram[sizes, "Log", "LogCount", Frame -> True], 
     ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{Rest@#[[1]], #[[2]]} &@HistogramList[sizes, "Log", "LogCount"]], 
                    Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Combination of the answers of jVincent and belisarius:

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[Log[sizes], 0.1];
Show[Histogram[sizes, "Log", "LogPDF", Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All], 
 LogLogPlot[PDF[dist, Log[x]]/x, {x, 10^3, 10^9}, 
  PlotRange -> 10^{-11, -4}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

It uses a smooth kernel with the uniform bandwidth `0.1` in the log scale.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in M11, you can just give [`SmoothHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram) the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) option:

```
data = Table[Sin[x]^3+1, {x, 0, 6 Pi, 0.1}];
SmoothHistogram[data, ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"}]
```

[image]

In M10, you can also use the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) option, but you will in addition need to specify the axes origin in transformed coordinates, e.g. (in M10.3.1):

```
data=Table[Sin[x]^3+1,{x,0,6 Pi,0.1}];
SmoothHistogram[data, ScalingFunctions->{"Log","Log"}, AxesOrigin->Log@{.002, .002}]
```

[image]